# How can I list the routes to all files being served by karma

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I'm using requirejs inside of karma to run my tests, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the actual urls to my files are.

Is there any way to list the files being served and the routes to access them?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're looking for. I also use karma and requirejs in my projects, here's the basic structure I use to start : https://github.com/glepretre/angular-requirejs-ready. 

Did you try to set `logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG` in your karma config? This way, you will see all files served in the (verbose) output.

Comment: Those show the files being served, but not the URLs that they are being served from

Comment: And in your browser developper tools, in the network tab, you don't find what you're looking for?

Comment: Have the same problem, karma always show '404', but I don't know what the correct url is

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can access object **window.__karma__** which has property **files**. You can iterate over it.

I just entered this code into my test-main.js:

```
for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
  console.log(file)
}
```

All served files would be printed to console among other messages. Here is sample from my output:

```
...
Firefox 32.0.0 (Ubuntu) LOG: '/base/node_modules/requirejs/require.js'
Firefox 32.0.0 (Ubuntu) LOG: '/base/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js'
Firefox 32.0.0 (Ubuntu) LOG: '/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js'
...
```